# SAS function to remove data if the month matches between 2 dates in 2 set of columns

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a large data with dates on 2 columns (15 years data). I am looking to remove the date if the month between the 2 columns match (dont care about the day or the year) EX: 01FEB2006 - 01FEB2017 now i need to remove this date as the month matches while 16FEB2006 - 23JUN2017 doesn't therefore i need a new column to say the difference is 4 months. If the difference is +/- 30 days between the 2 months, this have to be removed Ex: 01jan2005 - 20dec2014. 
Please help! I am still learning SAS. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Post sample data and what you've tried so far. SO is not a code writing service and you do need to attempt to solve this problem yourself first and then tell us what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The question is a bit unclear. But as I've deduced the question has number of potential questions:

**"Delete obeservations that have matching months"**

This may be obtained using month function. (Or if your date is string then substring.) http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000197966.htm

```
Data refined;
    set begin;
    month1=month(date_var1 );
    month2=month(date_var2 );

    if month1= month2 then delete; 
run;
```

**"I need a new column to say the difference is 4 months."**

intck if your friendly function here. You can calculate the timedifferences between the dates. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/INTCK_function_examples

```
Data refined;
    set begin;
    TimeDifference = intck('month', date_var1, date_var2);
run;
```

**"if datedifference is +-30 days then delete the observation"**

Same as above, but with days in this case.

```
Data refined;
    set begin;
    TimeDifference = intck('days', date_var1, date_var2) ;
    if abs(TimeDifference) <=30 delete;
run;
```